# React.js updating state vs immutability

Tags: reactjs, use-state, immer.js

Is there any option to add zone without maping it and adding new object into state on first click?

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-ellis-b7e8k?file=/src/App.js:319-324

My wanted behaviour is filling inputs and adding it into state on click. After added I will reset input to add more zones into state.

Someone told about using immer.js. Actually reading docs.. is there any other way?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Brendan,
I want to have inputs available without adding new object and when I fill inputs and click on "add" button I want it to be added into state.

Answer (score 0):

`useState` will require objects to be immutable to detect changes. So, array.push will usually not have the desired effect. Create a new one instead:

```js
onClick={() =>
  setZones([...zones, {
    Server: "",
    positionName: "",
    positionIdentification: ""
  }])
}
```

This will create a new array with the contents of the old plus the new content.

To avoid creating a new array every time, as you suggested immer can do that for you with the [useImmer](https://github.com/immerjs/use-immer) hook.

Comment: Can you give me hint with immer please? My brain cant get it sadly..

I tried 

```js
  const updateZone = useCallback((e, index) => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    setZones(
      produce((draft) => {
        draft[index] = {[name]: value }
      })
    );
  })
```

But its meh, probably not having all params I need.

Comment: You're almost there, try `setZones(produce(prevZones, draft => {..same as you..}))` or wrap the whole state with the useImmer hook. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly I wasn't successfull with both things.